# Sqlyog mysql access denied for user@ipaddress using password yes

Tags: mysql, access-denied, sqlyog

I have created a user via `SQLyog`.

**Created user on localhost**

[image]

**Given all global Privileges**

[image]

**When Trying to access**

[image]

I am getting above error when I am trying to access it

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: you've added access for a local user, i.e. from the same box as the db is hosted. Try specifying the ip of the client you're connecting from when creating the user, or using % to indicate any ip address. Also, (dont know if this is needed with the gui) but a 'flush privileges' is normally needed to activate any new perms.

Comment: @FreudianSlip previously I did `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` but nothing happens

Comment: @FreudianSlip also I am accessing the Local IP via VPN so that's why the user is created on the same IP i.e. localhost

Comment: try: CREATE USER 'my_username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_goes_here' with grant option; flush privileges.